# How to draw a custom shadow in GTK?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk3, cairo

I've created a custom window in GTK3 and set `decorated` to `False`, so the default window decoration is not rendered. That also removed a shadow from my window.

**How do I get the shadow back?**

Should I use Cairo library to draw it? If so, any tips on how to do that would be helpful.

I'm writing in Python, but examples in any language will work.